# Constructe concentration inequality for product variable.

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, probability-distributions, concentration-of-measure

Consider the sets of i.i.d. random variables $\{ X_i \}_{i = 1}^n$ and $\{ Y_i \}_{i = 1}^n$, which are independent of each other. Denote their sample means as $\overline{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$ and $\overline{Y} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i$, and their population means as $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$, respectively. We seek appropriate upper bounds $U_X$ and $U_Y$ for the population means such that
$$
    \mathrm{P} (\mu_X - \overline{X} > U_X) \leq \alpha / 2, \qquad  \mathrm{P} (\mu_Y - \overline{Y} > U_Y) \leq \alpha / 2.
$$
where $U_X$ and $U_Y$ are positive functions incorporating distribution information.

We wish to find a suitable upper bound $U_Z$ for the product of the population means, $\mu_Z = \mu_X  \mu_Y$, which represents the expected value of $Z_i = X_i Y_i$. We want to find a function $U_Z$ in terms of $\overline{X}, \overline{Y}, \overline{Z}, U_X, U_Y$ satisfying
$$
    \mathrm{P} (\mu_Z-  \overline{Z} > U_Z) \leq \alpha.
$$

PS: Previously, I tried $U_Z = \overline{X} U_Y + \overline{Y} U_X + U_X U_Y$ as
$$
 \mathrm{P} (\mu_Z -  \overline{Z}  > {\overline{X} U_Y  + \overline{Y} U_X + U_{X} U_Y}) \leq  \mathrm{P}  (\mu_X \mu_Y -  \overline{X} \cdot \overline{Y} > {\overline{X} U_Y  + \overline{Y} U_X + U_{X} U_Y}) =  \mathrm{P} \big( (\mu_X - \overline{X}) (\mu_Y  - \overline{Y}) > U_X U_Y \big) \leq \alpha.
$$
But it does not work, as I see we cannot guarantee that $\overline{Z} \geq \overline{X}\cdot \overline{Y}$. But I trust there is a similar expression.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun This is a question from my own research. I provided detailed context as well as detailed background. I also give my try in PS. It is so funny that this question is closed.

Comment: Your edit makes it acceptable. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "$\times$"? Usual multiplication of real numbers?

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes. I edited my question for clarifying. Thanks for your pointing out.